# Excel pivot table - wrong number ordering

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with number ordering in pivot tables. I tried almost everything... Observe:

As you can see somehow the pivot table sorts the days in a wrong order. In the data source all day values are numbers formatted as General - NOT DATES! Week numbers are number as well, again formatted as general.

Another interesting point is that a different pivot report which is using data from this file has the same issue. Note that the data is processed during the export and is converted to date using VBA DateValue function etc.

We use this report about a year now and we never had this issue before. Rebuilding the pivot table fixed the issue but in this report I have about 10 pivot tables and charts linked to VBA code, slicers, named cells etc. Rebuilding the whole file would take days.

Comment: Observe what? I can't see anything of relevance... ;)

Comment: Dusan, I guess you have a screenshot that you cannot post. Put in on a image sharing site, and link it to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I´ve added a picture but my karma or whatever wasn´t good or something :)

Anyway, thank you for your comments, I´ve already figured it out so here is my answer:

I´ve just selected the row which I wanted to sort and sorted it with the basic excel sorting tool in the Home tab. So stupid...

Sorry for bothering with such a stupid question... :)